# Locally disable navigation to external url's appearing in a website's UI (when running in kiosk mode)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, kiosk

I am displaying a multi-page website in an exhibition using firefox or chrome's kiosk mode with a live url. While most of the links in the website are in-domain, I do have some links pointing out. And because of the kiosk mode, once a user clicks one, it's hard for them to get back to the site. What would be a smart way to disable those links, under the following assumptions: (1) I prefer not to create a special or local version of the website and still use the live one which retains full functionality (2) the website includes iframes with external src and they should continue working (3) Getting an error page is not an option links should either be completely disabled or error pages should automatically navigate back.

Comment: I can see this needing some kind of [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/index.php?browser=chrome) solution, because you have to stop the behaviour before it even leaves the browser; preventing it from even starting to ask for the remote page & therefore presenting an error on being blocked. *How* to do that, I have no clue, but it might be a question for the mothership, Stack Overflow.